# How to retrieve number of checked items in checklistbox in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've been trying this for about 30 minutes and can't find an answer. 
How do I retrieve the number of checked items in a checklistbox in ASP?

Everywhere else on the internet says to use cblList.CheckedItems but the CheckedItems property isn't showing up for me in the Intellisense?  Am I forgetting to include something?  It's driving me bonkers.  I'm using VB.NET for this ASP assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CheckedItems` is a winforms property, the webforms [`CheckBoxList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  supports also multi-selection, but it does not provide a method or property to retrieve the selected items directly. But you could use this little LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<ListItem> selectedItems = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
 .Where(li => li.Selected);
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim selectedItems = From item In CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)()
                    Where item.Selected
```

If you don't want to use LINQ as commented,  use a loop:

```
Dim selected = New List(Of ListItem)
For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
    If item.Selected Then selected.Add(item)
Next
Dim numSelected = selected.Count
```

Comment: While that is helpful Tim, this is for a pretty basic assignment, and the professor might not take kind to using LINQ.  Is there any other way I can do it?  Through a for loop of any kind?  To see if each checkbox is selected at all?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, it is basically the same as a loop. So you could create a `List(Of ListItem)` and add them in the loop when the `Selected`. property returns `True`.  I've edited my answer.